# Не получаю данные $_POST В чём может быть проблема?

Tags: php, html, html-form

```
    <HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Заголовок </title>
</head>

<?php

//--------------------------------------------------------------

$forma = '
        <form name="form1" method="post" action="admin.php">
                <p>
                        <input type="text" name="$name" value="$name">Логин<br />
                </p>
                <p>
                        <input type="password" name="$user_pas" value="$user_pas">
                </p>
                <p>
                        <input type="submit" name="login" value="Войти">
                </p>

        </form>';

echo '<table>';
echo '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="spacer">';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td class="side-body">';
echo '<div style="text-align:center">';
echo $forma;
echo 'Вы не зарегистрированы?           <a href="register.php" class="side">Нажмите здесь</a> для регистрации.          Забыли пароль?          Запросите новый <a href="lostpassword.php" class="side">здесь</a>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';

//----------------------------------------

if (!empty($_POST['login']))
{
echo '=========>!';
$name=$_POST['name'];
echo "$name";
$user_pas=$_POST['user_pas'];
echo "$user_pas";
echo '!<=========';

}

?>
</html>
```

Запускаю этот скрипт Вожу имя и пароль нажимаю войти и получаю результат :

=========>!!<=========

переписал код всё равно не выдаёт значение

Comment: Это что за ересь?

    $_POST['name']=$name;
    $_POST['user_name']=$user_pas;

Comment: люди, которые все еще пишут html на капсе, мы будем убивать

Answer (score 1):

Внимательно смотрим на строчки `$_POST['name']=$name;` и `$_POST['user_pas']=$user_pas;`. Осознаём свою ошибку. Заменяем их на `$name=$_POST['name'];` и `$user_pas=$_POST['user_pas'];` соответственно.

Answer (score 1):

Вначале ознакомтесь подробней с разметкой HTML.

**Первое:**

```
<input type="text" name="$name">Логин<br />
```

name - имя поля которое будет передаваться в скрипт, оно не должно содержать спец. символов.
value - значение которое будет прописываться в поле ввода (можно сказать по умолчанию).

Пример:

```
<input type="text" name="user_name" value="$user_name">Логин<br />
```

**Второе:**

В PHP при использовании одинарных кавычек в тексте не парсятся переменные, только в двойных.

```
echo "user_name = $user_name";  - верно
echo 'user_name = $user_name';  - не верно
```

Конечно в разных случаях нам необходимы разные выводы текста.

Answer (score 0):

Это победа всего сегодняшнего дня

```
$_POST['name']=$name;
$_POST['user_pas']=$user_pas;
```

здесь вы затираете данные в $_POST несуществующими значениями. Надо наоборот:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

Comment: $name = $_POST['name']; 


Упсс всё понятно ))) Огромное спасибо

Comment: Думаете этим все глюки исправились? Для начала - посмотрите на исходник страницы...

Comment: Да не исправились глюки (((( переписал код (см выше ) результат тот же ((( Запускаю в Денвере

Comment: Вы исходник страницы уже посмотрели, или совет мимо ушей пропустили?

Comment: Нет ни какой страницы мне просто нужно написать скрипт для обработки данных пост в одном сценарии скрипт написан но данны не передаются

Comment: Ну продолжайте, продолжайте делать как вам удобней, может всё-таки выгонят - найдёте себе другое занятие по душе.